# Struts2 jQuery autocompleter not working

Tags: autocomplete, struts2, dojo, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

Currently I am doing struts up-gradation task (struts2.0 to struts2.5). I want to replace struts dojo tag with struts-jquery.

Here I am facing some issue when replace struts-dojo autocompleter to struts-jQuery autocompleter.

Getting below response from server :

```
  [
  {
    "firstName": "Bulwark Technologies LLC",
    "partnerId": 925
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Bulwark Technologies LLC1",
    "partnerId": 926
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Bulwark Technologies LLC2",
    "partnerId": 927
  }
]
```

For displaying at client side I am using Struts2-jquery-autocompleter -

```
<sj:autocompleter href="%{urlpartnerList}" list="%{partnerNameListBeanStruts2}" listValue="firstName" listKey="partnerId"/>
```

I am getting "undefined (multiple times - based on result found in query at server side)" in textbox.

Could some one please help here? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I think your attribute value for `list` is wrong. I always use something like this: `{"mylist": [ {"key": "1", "value": "Foo"}, { key: "2", value: "Bar"} ]}` and the autocompleter: `<sj:autocompleter href="..." list="mylist" listKey="key" listValue="value" />`

Comment: Thanks bother.I have done as you suggested and now it is working fine.But there is also one issue.When I am selecting element then on selection it will fill data with id.Like i searched "Bar" then I select bar from suggestion, in textbox it will show 2 on selection of "bar".What should i do here ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use the `label` attribute, take a look at the [Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) -> Widgets -> Autocompleter -> Autocompleter JSON

Comment: ok if i am using  <sj:autocompleter 
         id="partnerName" 
         name="partnerName"
         href="%{urlPartnerName}" 
         list="partnerNameListBeanStruts2Map"
         label="partnerId"
         listValue="firstName" 
         listKey="partnerId" 
         loadMinimumCount="2" 
         />  then it is working fine but then in search criteria how can i get value of lable element ?

Comment: Hi Sir could you please suggest me something here ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions in the comments lead you in the wrong direction, with this `<sj:autocompleter/>` it should work perfectly fine without changing it the server response. I messed up with the various options, that are available for this tag.

```
<sj:autocompleter href="%{jsonAction}" listKey="partnerId" listValue="firstName" name="firstname"/>
```

> how can i get the value of the label element?

The trick with this autocompleter is, that the `listValue` is shown as selection in the visible text field but the `listKey` is used as value in a hidden field. And this hidden field will be used to send the value back to the server. That should also answer your question:

The `<sj:autocompleter/>` will create following html code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="HERE_IT_WILL_PUT_THE_LIST_KEY"/>
<input type="text" name="firstname_widget" value="HERE_IT_WILL_PUT_THE_LIST_VALUE"/>
```

Thus you only have to set the `listKey` tag with the list property name you want to have as a response.